# Split data into groups and show the used and available values in Tableau

Tags: if-statement, tableau-api, visualization

I have some data here:

Where I would like to break into 2 groups and calculate them differently.

**A,B,C is group 1 which should be the AVERAGE**

**X,Y,Z is group 2 which should be the SUM**

and show the available, used and avail%, used% on a bar graph across the given dates

```
The used = Total_Backup - Available

Avail% = (sum(total)/sum(total),2)

Used% = (sum(used)/sum(total))





total_backup sku available date

10            A         5 Sept 19

20            B         10 Sept 19

30            B         15 Sept 19

10            C         5 Sept 19

10            C         5 Sept 19

10            Z         5 Sept 19

10            Z         5 Sept 19

20            Y         10 Sept 19

30            Y         15 Sept 19

40            X         10 Sept 19

40            A         20 Sept 20

20            A         10 Sept 20

10            B         5 Sept 20

40            C         20 Sept 20

50            C         25 Sept 20

10            Z         5 Sept 20

10            Z         5 Sept 20

20            Y         10 Sept 20

10            X         5 Sept 20
```

desired output, but I may have to show different bars based on group 1 and group 2

**My dilemma is :
creating these groups that have different calculations:**

**A,B,C is group 1** which should be the **AVERAGE**

**X,Y,Z is group 2** which should be the **SUM**

[image]

Any suggestion is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Still you haven't given desired output.  Please give desired output in a text table at least!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok finally I got the solution-

You have to reshape your data before proceeding to create any view.  Tableau generally prefers long pivoted form of data where any of the variable values should not be used as any column name.  Instead all variable values be used in values only.

Proceed like this -

**Step-1** Calculate `used` column in data prep software (you can do wherever your data is stored e.g. in excel, tableau Prep etc.).  Thereafter your total column will be of no use.  I changed your sample data a bit because everywhere you showed 50% of storage as used and balance used thereby resulting in `used = available` everywhere.  The data used is

```
total_backup    sku available   date    used
10  A   5   Sep-19  5
20  B   5   Sep-19  15
30  B   10  Sep-19  20
10  C   5   Sep-19  5
10  C   5   Sep-19  5
10  Z   1   Sep-19  9
10  Z   1   Sep-19  9
20  Y   10  Sep-19  10
30  Y   10  Sep-19  20
40  X   10  Sep-19  30
40  A   15  Sep-20  25
20  A   10  Sep-20  10
10  B   5   Sep-20  5
40  C   15  Sep-20  25
50  C   15  Sep-20  35
10  Z   5   Sep-20  5
10  Z   2   Sep-20  8
20  Y   5   Sep-20  15
10  X   2   Sep-20  8
```

**Step-2** connect with tableau.  hide/discard total column.  Thereafter pivot `used` and `available` columns.  Your data tab should look like this thereafter (of course I have changed pivoted col names)

[image]

**Step-3** Create groups on SKU fields, as desired.  I have created two groups with names `sum group` and `avg group` respectively.

**Step-4** Create two calculated fields `sumg val` and `avgg val` with the following calculations respectively

1. `sum(if [Sku (group)]= 'sum group' then [val] end)`
2. `AVG(if [Sku (group)]= 'avg group' then [val] end)`

**Stepo-5** Build your desired view by using dual axis and synchronizing axes.  You'll get a view (after a little color tweak)-

[image]

Good luck.

Comment: Ok thank you @AnilGoyal I have tried but I need the total column to be in tableau ad well. I will use your post as a foundation. Thank you

Comment: How would I Combine the Groups (while keeping the calculated sum and average)  and not make it separate? I am working on it and I will create a new post. Thank you

Comment: What is your combination operator in that case? Do you want to add these two results?

Comment: Yes add them. I was working on this tonight but still not able to do this.m in the chart. 1. Group by a specific Id, 2. Sum one group, average the other group 3. Display avail , used and total on bar graph ( but combine those two groups in the bar chart)

Comment: Like in your previous question you want to display 8?

Comment: Hi @AnilGoyal, I wish to have: for 2019 (on your chart above) the orange would be added to equal 10+78 = 88 used ; and the blue would added to be: 6+32 = 38 . So 88 used (orange) and 38 available (blue) —- and for 2020 to be: used (orange) 20+36 = 56 and avail (blue) 12+14 = 26. Is this possible? (But the total column should be there too so that I can see it in the tooltip) Thank you I will keep researching

Comment: @Lynnette, you mean you want this in another question? right?